# React state hook doesn't properly handle async data

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api

I'm trying to set a component's state through an effect hook that handles the backend API. Since this is just a mock, I'd like to use the vanilla react methods and not something like redux-saga.

The problem is that while the fetching part works, the useState hook doesn't update the state.

```js
const [odds, setOdds] = useState({})

useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
        fetchMock.once('odds', mocks.odds)
        let data = await fetch('odds').then(response => response.json())
        setOdds(data)
        console.log(odds, data) // {}, {...actual data}
    })()
}, [])
```

I've tried to pipe the whole process on top of the fetch like

```js
fetch('odds')
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => setOdds(data))
.then(() => console.log(odds)) // is still {}
```

But it doesn't make a single difference.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically if you call `setOdds`, the value of `odds` does not change immediately. It is still the last reference available at decleration of the hook.

If you want to access the new value of `odds` after updating it, you would have to either use the source of the updated value (`data`) if you want to access the value in the same `useEffect` hook or create another `useEffect` hook that triggers only when `odds` has changed:

```
useEffect(() => {

    console.log(odds);
    // Do much more

}, [odds]) // <- Tells the hook to run when the variable `odds` has changed.
```

Comment: This is the right answer! Apparently if I don't add it to the dependency array, it doesn't get properly updated. This used to cause issues with the hook running itself recursively ad infinitum, but I found a way around. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see that state has changed in here, you can use

```
const [odds, setOdds] = useState({})

useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
        fetchMock.once('odds', mocks.odds)
        let data = await fetch('odds').then(response => response.json())
        setOdds(prevData => {
          console.log(prevData, data) // {}, {...actual data}
          return data
        })

    })()
}, [])
```